# Регулярка для meta name robots

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Имеем вот такую регулярку:

```
'#<meta\s*name\s*=\s*["\']robots["\']\s*content\s*=\s*["\'](.*?)["\']\s*/>#si'
```

Отлично отрабатывает для

```
<meta name="robots" content="all" />
```

но возникают проблемы для

```
<meta name="robots" content="all">
```

или `<meta name="robots" content="all" >`

Подскажите, как поправить для обработки обоих вариантов?
Про get_meta_tags знаю - не подходит.

Comment: @theblackpost, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

1. Скачиваем и подключаем Symfony/Crawler и Symfony/CSS-Selector

```
wget https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar -O composer
php composer require symfony/dom-crawler:* symfony/css-selector:*
```

2. Подключаем Crawler в проект

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Crawler;
```

3. Используем по назначению

```
$crawler = new Crawler($html);
$metaRobots = $crawler->filter('meta[name="robots"]');
if ($metaRobots->count()) {
    $content = $metaRobots->first()->attr('content');
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за интересную вещь!
Пока немного подпилил регулярку. Вроде работает:
preg_match('#<meta\s*name\s*=\s*["\']robots["\']\s*content\s*=\s*["\'](.*?)["\']\s*/?>#si',$charrz, $metamatch)

Comment: @theblackpost, я не просто так не стал исправлять приведенную регулярку. При наличии трех целей в документе потребуется уже три зубодробительные регуялрки, которые время от времени придется перепиливать. Краулер же добавит дополнительный уровень абстракции, отделит конкретный тег от тегов вообще и позволит быть уверенным в полученном результатею

Comment: Подскажи, а как использовать краулер, например для тегов div, strong и т.п. ?

Comment: @theblackpost, метод `->filter($selector)` возвращает новый краулер, содержащий уже только элементы, соответствующие этому селектору. Например, `$crawler->filter('div')` вернет новый краулер со всеми дивами, а `$crawler->fitler('strong, b')` вернет краулер с тегами strong и b. С помощью `->eq($i)` можно получить элемент с номером $i, а `->count()` скажет общее количество элементов. Таким образом, если надо вытянуть содержимое всех параграфов, то код будет такой:

Comment: .

    $crawler = new Crawler($html);
    $paragraphCrawler = $crawler->filter('p');
    $paragraphs = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < ;paragraphCrawler->count(); $i++) {
        $paragraphs[] = $paragraphCrawlerr->eq($i)->html();
    }

больше примеров и описания можно найти на [странице документации](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html)

Comment: @Etki последний вопрос. Сорри, за навязчивость))

то есть. если мне надо вытащить кол-во тегов одного типа, например, 'div',
пишем так:
<pre>
function crawl() {
  $crawler = new Crawler($html);
  $divCrawler = $crawler->filter('div');
  $divs = array();
  for ($i = 0; $i < ;divsCrawler->count(); $i++) {
    $divs[] = $divsCrawler->count($i)->html();
    return $divs[];
    }
}
</pre>

Comment: @theblackpost, нет, тут будет чуть-чуть попроще. `$divsCrawler->count()` уже вернет нужное число тегов.

Чтобы запустить его, надо поработать с [неймпейсами](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.php) и [Composer](http://habrahabr.ru/post/145946/) и подключить автозагрузчик последнего (он всегда будет располагаться по адресу vendor/autoload.php относительно папки выполнения composer require), но это того стоит и сэкономит кучу времени в дальнейшем. Вышеописанная директива use тоже обязательна, чтобы писать просто `new Crawler` без полного пути к классу.